# Add more than one tables in RDLC

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, rdlc, dynamic-rdlc-generation

As question states I want to add more than one table in RDLC report. I have added one table in few reports. But don't know how to add multiple tables in a single report. I am adding tables using `objects` as `DataSource`. My database is `SQLite`.

I found a tutorial to make `rdlc` using `object` as `datasource` [here.](http://www.mindstick.com/Articles/13169999-ef3b-496c-b502-caef973c3bb2/Using%20ReportViewer%20in%20WinForms%20C) But that does not say about multiple tables. How to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can do this following steps given below ,

1.Create 2 dataset in RDLC file in respect to each table

2.Pass these 2 dataset from your code

```
ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource("dsChart",ObjectDataSource1);

ReportDataSource rds2 = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1",ObjectDataSource2);

rptViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();

rptViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);

rptViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds2);
```

moreover you can relate with this [tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/473844/Using-Custom-Data-Source-to-create-RDLC-Reports)